# "Как мужик с мужиком". Сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

*Давай выйдем и поговорим (?) как мужик с мужиком*. Является ли здесь *как мужик с мужиком* сравнительным оборотом и нужно ли поставить перед *как* запятую?

Comment: Интуитивно чувствую, что запятая вроде нужна, но мне тоже нужно объяснение, так что спасибо за вопрос! Сам задумывался над подобными примерами в последние дни и хотел какой-то помощи в этом.

Comment: Я рад тому, что вопрос Вам интересен, Артём.

Comment: Я, как всегда, оказался неправ насчёт запятой.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос не такой однозначный, **разные** могут быть решения:

**1) Не обособляется:** устойчивое выражение в роли обстоятельства:

Давай поговорим как мужик с мужиком (откровенно).Если все так, то позвони и поговори со мной как мужик с мужиком.

**2) Обособляется:** неполное сравнительное предложение (как мужик поговорил бы с мужиком):
Не, просто объясни мне, как мужик мужику ― чё ты лезешь в чужой огород?

**3) Второе обстоятельство:** А скажи мне откровенно, как мужик мужику, что, для тебя не престижно поехать на гастроли с «Виртуозами Москвы»?

4) **Сочетание "как мужики"** не обособляется в таких ситуациях с большим основанием: Давай поговорим как мужики.

Comment: Конечно, одно и тоже устойчивое выражение в зависимости от ситуации может обособляться, а может - нет.  Речь шла об этом примере, я ответил на данный вопрос.

Comment: В заданном предложении решение также факультативно, хотя запятую здесь лучше не ставить. Но это решение зависит от структуры предложения (распространенное или нераспространенное), от позиции оборота. Здесь одним смысловым анализом не обойдешься, учитывая распространенность самого оборота и его возможную соотнесенность с неполным придаточным предложением.

Comment: Аналогичное предложение: Они разговаривают как чужие. Здесь ведь тоже можно отнести оборот с как к неполному придаточному ( как разговаривают чужие).  Нужно учитывать и структуру, и роль оборота в предложении, и семантику. Я бы не стал бы утверждать,что запятая факультативна.

Comment: В данном случае все же,мне кажется, это простое предложение с обст-ом.

Comment: Серж, в вашем ответ про структуру ничего не говорится, объяснение непонятное. И про неполное предложение: в неполном (двусоставном) предложении пропущено только одно сказуемое, а подлежащее и дополнение присутствуют.

Comment: Серж, мне всё понятно, вы лучше Артему ответьте, у него к вам вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, Vera !

Answer (score 1):

В примере, который Вы приводите, сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** характеризует предмет лишь с одной стороны. В этом случае запятая не ставится.

Ср.: Они разговаривают как чужие; Переговоры с ним надлежало вести как с равной стороной;Я сохраню это письмо как память;

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь.Д.Э.

Comment: А не можете пояснить, Серж, что значит "с одной стороны", а то я врубится не могу? Как тогда в других случаях - с двух или больше сторон? Не могу понять, что под этим подразумевается... Спасибо!

Comment: Артем, это не значит, что в других случаях предмет характеризуется с нескольких сторон и тогда запятая ставится. Характеристика предмета с одной стороны - значит в нем выделяется один признак.

Comment: Спасибо, если честно, всё равно не очень понял конкретно, что имеется в виду под признаком и не могу это понять без примеров, ну да ладно, чтобы не засорять комментарии, забью на это.

Comment: Артем, имеется в виду, что оборот представляет из себя приложение.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж !